# W/Intercom realtime: No realtime endpoints present so we can't connect

Tags: android, intercom

My App that uses Intercom displays this warning at runtime. So does the [official sample app](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/tree/master/samples).

> ```
> W/Intercom realtime: No realtime endpoints present so we can't connect
> ```

What is the purpose of this warning, and how can I fix it?

---

If it helps, here is a bit more log context using `Intercom.setLogLevel(Intercom.LogLevel.VERBOSE);` before the `Intercom.initialize(...);` call:

```
[Intercom] Dispatched Action: SET_LAUNCHER_VISIBILITY: VISIBLE
[Intercom] Started observing md5asdfasdfasdfasdfasfd.MainActivity@57e44d4
[Intercom realtime] No realtime endpoints present so we can't connect
[Intercom] Dispatched Action: SESSION_STARTED: No Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it mean there is no realtime update when new message comming. I got this problem when implement Intercom chat on Android.And when checking log cat I got this message also